# Disappearance of 3D axis from viewport

Tags: 3d-view, axis, interface

In my recent project work, I did something that resulted in the disappearance of the 3D axis in the viewport of the "Layout" workspace, not only that all that four buttons(including zoom thingy, move, camera and projection buttons). I am not sure what lead to this. Weirdly, both 3D axis and 4 buttons exist in all workspaces except in "Layout".(screenshot attached)

I googled to check the problem and found a similar issue caused using transform hotkey([devtalk blender](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/disappearing-3d-viewport-axis-when-using-transform-hotkeys-2-8/2355)). Although I didn't do anything similar.

Is this a bug? How can I resolve this?

Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Type: Blender LTS
Blender Version: 2.83.14

Missing 3D axis in viewport of Layout workspace
[image: Missing 3D axis in viewport of Layout workspace]
3D axis i am talking about, as u can see this appears in all other blender workspaces
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Interactive Navigation* controls can be toggled by pressing the gizmo icon in the upper right corner of the 3D view or by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (backtick not single quote/apostrophe).

[image: 1]

Comment: thank you. It worked.